# Aggregation by ID on Elasticsearch or by timestamp with unsupervised clustering

Tags: elasticsearch, grouping, cluster-analysis, aggregation

I have a data log entry stored in elasticsearch, each with its own timestamp. I now have a dashboard that can get the aggregation by day / week using Date Histogram aggregation.

Now I want to get the data in chunk (data logs are written several time per transaction, spanning for up to several minutes) by analyzing the "cluster" of logs according to its timestamp to identify whether it's the same "transaction". Would that be possible for Elastic search to automatically analyze the meaningful bucket and aggregate the data accordingly?

Another approach I'm trying is to group the data by transaction ID - however there's a warning that to do this I need to enable fielddata which will use a significant amount of memory. Any suggestion?

Comment: Usually transactions are grouped by its transaction UUID which is either generated upon transaction start or supplied by the client app. But the first approach is obscure a little bit: _according to its timestamp to identify whether it's the same "transaction"_ - could you please elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: @PaulVasilev sorry I think the word is "session" i.e. the person could have an average session time of several seconds up to several hours. I want to group (or bucket) these data log by transaction. If I use terms aggregation on Elasticsearch I needed to enable fielddata.